# error ionic 4 ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

Tags: ios, angular, ionic4

i have message from apple :

App Store Connect

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Project 66" 0.0.9 (0.0.9). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

Best regards,

The App Store Team

any solution to fix this issue ??

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/11/25/cordova-ios-release-5.1.0.html

Answer (score 5):

The cordova team yesterday released 2019-11-25 a release cordova-ios@5.1.0
This release resolves the ITMS-90809 alert from the apple store.

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios@5.1.0

Add <preference name = "WKWebViewOnly" value = "true" /> to your config.xml file

Run "cordova prepare ios" to apply the changes.
```

To recap:

- 5.1.0 has a conditional compile time flag that disables UIWebView. This is an initial fix to prevent the Apple warning from being
  triggered.
  6.0.0 will remove the entirety of UIWebView. This is a breaking change with more changes needed, so it’ll be released sometime in the
  coming months.

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/11/25/cordova-ios-release-5.1.0.html#comment-4702612854

https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using native app development then you have to use WKWebview instead of UIWebview. You also have to updated all third party framework which are using UIWebview.

If you are using cross platform then you have to wait untill they will update their framework to using WKwebview.

You can also contact to your cross platform support team and report the issue.